# Reading network activity logs on Android

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-permissions, android-log

Can we read the app intra / inter net activity log on Android programmatically without having root access? If yes, can we do so for all apps on the device?

Answer (score 0):

For your application yes, it is possible, but you need to use some layer in the HTTP requests that handles the requests and logs the information.

For example using retrofit:

```
setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setLog(new AndroidLog("YOUR_LOG_TAG"))
```

For all the applications in the device you need root, or install a custom proxy, for example: http://www.charlesproxy.com/ but with charles proxy you cannot do that programmatically...