# Log all user and network activities Android

Tags: android, logging, proxy

I would like to create logfiles of the activities on my Android phone.

The goal is to be able to trace back any suspicious activities of apps and check if the phone's been hacked.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212444/reading-network-activity-logs-on-android) someone suggested using a proxy server.
But using a proxy changes the ip used and a lot of services (i.e. Netflix) block mobile traffic coming from either server ip's or home ip's when making mobile requests.
The question is already 3.5 years old so maybe the options have changed.

As for the network traffic an option to setup a local proxy on the device itself with a possibility to set logging rules would work though.

How could you setup a local proxy on an Android device?

However this is only the first part as to find possible suspicious activities. But without logging the actual phone activities it will be difficult (or impossible) to actually find out which malicious code or app is doing this.

How can we log activities on Android?

I think when loggin all user activities like touch events etc. and all calls between apps would suffice.

Can this be done without rooting the device? And if not how would one do this on a rooted device?

I would prefer to have this device independent, but I use an Oneplus 6 with Oxygen OS.

Comment: No. This cannot be done without rooting the device. And for a good reason.

Comment: @fjc okay and if I would root my device. Do you know what would be the easiest way to get the information?